# Using htmlagilitypack to capture 'p class' in a website

Tags: powershell, html-agility-pack

I want to capture this '**text**' shown int he picture below on a loop every minute, as this text changes every few minutes.

[image]

Here's the code I am using, and using **HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument**

```
$metro = 'greatesthits'
$URL = "https://triplem.scadigital.com.au/stations/$metro/live"
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Users\makean\Downloads\htmlagilitypack.1.8.10\lib\Net45\HtmlAgilityPack.dll")
[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb]$web = @{}
[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument]$doc = $web.Load($url)
$doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//*[contains(@class,'sc-bdVaJa iHZvIS')]")
```

This is slimier code below, does the same thing, however just a different way of doing it

```
$metro = 'greatesthits'
$URL = "https://triplem.scadigital.com.au/stations/$metro/live"
Add-Type -path 'C:\Users\makean\Downloads\htmlagilitypack.1.8.10\lib\Net45\HtmlAgilityPack.dll'
$doc = New-Object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$doc.LoadHtml($wc.DownloadString($url))
$doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//*[contains(@class,'sc-bdVaJa iHZvIS')]")
```

This class **sc-bdVaJa iHZvIS** is a div and sits just a bit higher than **PlayerNowPlaying__TrackInfo-kia103-1 gDXfGh** and **PlayerNowPlaying__TrackInfo-kia103-1 gDXfGh** is what I want to capture, however when using this in my code, it returns blank.

How can I return just the text I want? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. You can't achieve this using HtmlAgilityPack, as content that you are trying to get is loaded via ajax. 2. Do you really need to use Powershell scripts? It is much better/simpler to use java or c# to accomplish this task (using headless Selenium WebDriver) and if it's acceptable I can show and example. Afterwards you can even compile my example to .dll and wrap it with Powershell script.

Comment: I am only familiar with PowerShell (IT Pro background), and I am familiar with loading .dll files into PowerShell, and no real exposure to Java of C# - if you want to show me something new, I'd be very keen to learn.

Comment: Marc, sorry for late answer, was a bit busy. So I've prepared everything here: https://pastebin.com/GK2JGt3H. All information and screenshot with usage are there. If you feel that this is what you need - I can duplicate my answer here at stackoverflow as well.

Answer (score 0):

I looked further at the thanks to the person above who pointed me in the right direction, checked the network option in Chrome 'inspect'. Grabbed the metadata from the stream URL.

```
$metro = '2classicrock'
$URL = 'https://wz2web.scahw.com.au/live/' + $metro + '_32.stream/playlist.m3u8'
$null = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL).RawContent -match '(https.*m3u8.*)'
$StreamURL = $Matches[0]

$streamMetaData = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $StreamURL
$null = $streamMetaData.RawContent -match '#EXTINF:4.*?,(.*)'
$Matches[1]
```

Comment: I noticed that my answer didn't quite resolve the problem... Is it ok now?